# Convert Json Singleton into List Phone 81 UAP

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8.1

I am using http client to return a json response from a webservice. The example I am following here is from code project tutorial. However its example only returns into a var, it was created for the method to be called on screen I am changing it to be called from within a class. I have removed the webservice for security.

My Main question is how would I change this function to return a List of cinemas instead of the var variable I have a class created as such. I tried changing var into List but i noticed json.net handles this list so I need return the var as a known object instead I think?.

```
public class City
{
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string timing_title { get; set; }
}
public class Citys
{
        public List<City> city { get; set; }
}
```

I just don't know what to do to convert this so it returns a list of citys for me to use in function.

This is a list of example json data returned.

> {"city":[{"id":"5521","timing_title":"Lahore"},{"id":"5517","timing_title":"Karachi"},{"id":"5538","timing_title":"Islamabad"},{"id":"5535","timing_title":"Rawalpindi"},{"id":"5518","timing_title":"Hyderabad"},{"id":"5512","timing_title":"Faisalabad"},{"id":"8028","timing_title":"Gujranwala"},{"id":"8027","timing_title":"Gujrat"}]}

```
public  async void GetCinemasList()
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("webserviceurl");
            var url = "index.php/webservice/upcoming_movie";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var cityData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<City>(data.Result.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("Some Error Occured");
    }
}
```

Comment: no reason in world to mark down whoever did that its just out of spite i have included my example test data and what I have done !

Answer (score 0):

You have a `string` holding a JSON value.

You can parse and iterate through JSON values like this:

```
var data = "{\"city\":[{\"id\":\"5521\",\"timing_title\":\"Lahore\"},{\"id\":\"5517\",\"timing_title\":\"Karachi\"},{\"id\":\"5538\",\"timing_title\":\"Islamabad\"},{\"id\":\"5535\",\"timing_title\":\"Rawalpindi\"},{\"id\":\"5518\",\"timing_title\":\"Hyderabad\"},{\"id\":\"5512\",\"timing_title\":\"Faisalabad\"},{\"id\":\"8028\",\"timing_title\":\"Gujranwala\"},{\"id\":\"8027\",\"timing_title\":\"Gujrat\"}]}";

JsonObject rootObject;
if (JsonObject.TryParse(data, out rootObject))
{
    JsonArray cityArray = rootObject.GetNamedArray("city");
    foreach (var jsonValue in cityArray)
    {
        JsonObject cityObject = jsonValue.GetObject();
        Debug.WriteLine(cityObject.GetNamedString("timing_title"));
    }
}
else
{
    // Invalid JSON data.
}
```

Output:

```
Lahore
Karachi
Islamabad
Rawalpindi
Hyderabad
Faisalabad
Gujranwala
Gujrat
```